# Entity Framework with multiple models (different providers)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application working with Entity Framework and I have the same database schema in two different database engines (Oracle and MySQL). The database is the same in Oracle and MySQL. The application should work with this two providers because I have two different scenarios.

When I want to work in the Oracle Scenario I have to change manually the Web.Config to put the correct ConnectionString, the correct provider for member authentication, roleManager ..., and I have to delete the Database Model (edmx file) and recreate it for Oracle.

When I want to change working from Oracle to MySQL I have the same problem. I have to change the web.config to put the correct providers and the connection string and I have to recreate the database model (edmx file) for MySQL model.

Is there any way to avoid this heavy and boring task every time that I want to change the database?

Comment: Just create 2 edmx file. That's it

Comment: This is not a good option I think, because if I have two edmx (one for oracle and one for mysql) with the same database schema (same tables and fields) I will have compilation errors because of having classes with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is possible to create multiple Web.config and to automatically select the right one depending on the current used environment.

Additional information can be found [here](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100).

Comment: Yes, this solution helps me, but the big problem that I have is having to recreate the edmx file for different providers (delete the edmx file and create it for the required provider).